# Aurelia - Adding Font-Awesome to a webpack asp.net aurelia project

Tags: aurelia

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2, latest Aurelia/Aurelia CLI and I have been looking to install Font-Awesome however this does not appear to be that straightforward.

I see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122148/aurelia-cli-font-awesome) however I do not have an aurelia.json file. This appears to also be a requirement in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271458/how-can-i-add-font-awesome-to-my-aurelia-project-using-npm) as well.

It appears to not be as simple as just adding it via npm.

Given I have an ASP.NET 2 project, Webpack and no aurelia.json file (I do have a package.json if thats what they are referring to) whats the process of including Font Awesome in this regard?

Comment: I'm trying to work it out too... so far Iv'e got the "<require from..." tag in my template working, that tries to pull int he CSS, but I'm stuck as to how I get web pack to pull in the fonts.  No answer yet, but if I figure it out, I'll come back and answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so this turned out to be such a chore to figure out, but at the end of the day, the answer was actually a simple two liner.

I looked at a number of solutions, tried a number of different things, yet time and time again I kept getting what was apparently web-pack ignoring my rules, and just trying to load things as it pleases.

After looking at a number of other stack overflow posts and spending a good few hours trying different bit's in my webpack.config.js file (and the vendor one that gets produced by the dotnet core 2 template), I eventually figured out the following:

- 1) npm install the version of font awesome you wish to use.
- 2) In your app.html file, make sure it looks as follows:

```html
<template>
  <require from="./app.css"></require>
  <require from="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"></require>

  ... rest of your html here ... 

</template>
```

- 3) Edit your *webpack.config.js* file so that your rules section looks as follows (This is the most important part)

```js
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'ts-loader?silent=true' },
        { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
        { test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
      ]
    },
```

If you have other rules you need to keep, then you'll need to merge them and make sure you have no duplicates, or anything like that.

This is a similar answers to others that are on here, but as Iv'e found the other ones just don't seem to work with the dotnet core 2 spa template, where as this one does.

I suspect that as others have said it is something to do with the reg-ex.

One more thing to note.

If you look in *webpack.vendor.config.js* , you'll see that there is already a rule in there to handle font files, but that seems to get ignored for anything but a simple non versioned statically included file to override the general font, so I left mine in.

Altering the one that's present just doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

font-awesome installation has changed a bit with new versions. Moreover aurelia-cli has changed and improved a lot in past few months.

Above answers might not work anymore. Please check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122148/aurelia-cli-font-awesome/55468073#55468073) for webpack based aurelia-cli generated project.